# how to overlap datetime window in one file with datetime in another?

Tags: pandas, datetime

How can I average the values in input2 based on the overlap between datetime in input2 with input1 datetime window.

input1

```
2013-01-01 02:00:00 2013-01-02 03:00:00
2013-01-01 04:00:00 2013-01-01 04:30:00
2013-01-02 04:00:00 2013-01-01 04:30:00
```

input2

```
2013-01-01 02:01:00 10
2013-01-01 02:02:00 20
2013-01-01 02:03:00 30
2013-01-01 02:04:00 40
2013-01-02 02:04:00 40
```

Expected output

```
2013-01-01 02:00:00 2013-01-02 03:00:00 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NB. I changed a bit your example for clarity.*

You can use an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) to map date ranges for [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(pd.to_datetime(df1['date1']),
                                   pd.to_datetime(df1['date2']))

mapper = pd.Series(idx, index=idx)

df2.groupby(mapper[pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])].values)['value'].mean()
```

output:

```
(2013-01-01 02:00:00, 2013-01-02 03:00:00]    25.0
(2013-01-02 04:00:00, 2013-01-02 04:30:00]    40.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Used inputs:

```
# df1
                 date1                date2
0  2013-01-01 02:00:00  2013-01-02 03:00:00
1  2013-01-01 04:00:00  2013-01-01 04:30:00
2  2013-01-02 04:00:00  2013-01-02 04:30:00

# df2
                  date  value
0  2013-01-01 02:01:00     10
1  2013-01-01 02:02:00     20
2  2013-01-01 02:03:00     30
3  2013-01-01 02:04:00     40
4  2013-01-02 04:04:00     40
```